# Regaining access to existing Influxdb database instance v1.7.7

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have a business application running several IoT devices that send their data to an influx instance through a telegraf agent. The individual that initially deployed this project is inaccessible, but left behind credentials to access the various services in the tech stack. However, the only username and password pair that does not work is the one associated with the admin user for our influxdb. Is there a way to recover a password or alter the user credentials through the linux shell without destroying the significant amount of logged data and rebuilding the database from zero? I have found several solutions, but the recovery command wasn’t added until v2.2 and I have been unable to locate an influxdb.bolt file that might contain hints as to what the correct credentials are.

An alternate solution might be updating the instance version from 1.7.7 to 2.2 or later, and then utilizing the recovery command. Is this something that is possible without having admin credentials and also preserving the existing data?